# Are Cocoa input events thread safe with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, nstimer

Are input events in Cocoa like `(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` and `(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent` thread safe and synced with NSTimer events firing?

Can I have an NSTimer event accessing the same memory as a touch input event would? Would this be thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimer` events fire on the thread where you scheduled the timer.  If you scheduled the timer on the main run loop, then the timer will fire on the main thread and be “safe and synced” with input events.

It is possible, but probably unusual, to create a timer in one thread and schedule it to fire on a different thread.  If you're not sure which thread you scheduled the timer on, show us the code that creates and schedules the timer, and tell us which thread that code runs on.

Comment: Thanks Rob, yes, I am running the timer and input events off the main thread.

Comment: Did I answer your question or is there something left that you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, you answered my question.